# Irrationality measure, fractions representing approximations of an irrational number

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mu$ be the [irrationality measure](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html) of an irrational number $a$. This means that for any $s\lt\mu$ we have infinite sequencies of integers $(p_n)$, $(q_n)$ such that:

$$\left|\space a - \frac{p_n}{q_n} \right|\le \frac{1}{q_n^s}$$

In layman's terms this simply means that fractions $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ are "good" approximations of $a$.

Some of these fractions are less than $a$ and some of them are greater than $a$. That's why we use absolute value in the definition of irrationality measure.

**Question**: Can we prove that we have infinitely many fractions $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ on both sides of $a$?

Now comes the part where I should explain my own research but I'm afraid that my hands are empty.

Comment: The best approximations to a real irrational come from the convergents to its continued fraction, and these convergents alternate between over- and underestimates. So you might try to figure out what happens if, say, all the odd partial quotients are small (like, say, 1) while enough of the even convergents are large to make the irrationality measure large.

Comment: Your question can be understood in two different ways: (1) For any $s < \mu$ and any two "$s$-good" sequences $(p_n), (q_n)$ there are infinitely many $p_n/q_n$ on both sides of $a$ (2)  For any $s < \mu$ there exist two "$s$-good" sequences $(p_n), (q_n)$ such that there are infinitely many $p_n/q_n$ on both sides of $a$.

Comment: As Gerry said: could it happen that the even convergents of the continued fraction are very close, but the odd convergents are not so close?  Oldboy, have you learned about continued fractions?

Comment: @PaulFrost: I had option (2) in mind.

Comment: @GEdgar: Learned just the basics, improving. Obviously not fast enough.